# What is the name for the iterative paramater in a for loop in context of graphs?

Tags: loops, math, graph, loop-counter

Suppose you have a function that iterates x value over some kind of a range or an interval, like so:

```
for (x = MIN_CONST; x <= MAX_CONST; $x += STEP_CONST)
{
    //x is a ____ (what)?
    y = library_function(x);
    print y
}
```

An x value (out of sequential x values assigned inside the loop) can be seen as a "probe" or an "iterant", or "something".

I am looking for a defined, (or a better) name for this value.

If you like you can imagine a teacher explaining Newton's Method to students, and each x value gotten via the method would be called _____ what?

Comment: Maybe a ['domain value'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) (for the transformation done inside the iterator)? Although that implies no concept of sequence or ordering.

Comment: It is not au courant, but the word *abscissa* for the x-coordinate and *ordinate* for the y-coordinate have a historical currency (related somewhat distantly to tables for aiming munitions).  If I thought it would help those who maintained your code, I would make a stronger recommendation.

Comment: In the context of functions, this is the input (variable) or the argument.

Answer (score 2):

The general word for this is ***loop control variable***. See: [loop control variable on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_variable#In_computer_programming)

However, note that the two examples you are giving are not quite the same.

In the first case (i.e. in the `for`-loop) I would say that your `x` is basically a [**loop counter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_counter) that you are using as an **input argument** for a function. (Although loop counter is not quite precise, since you are not requiring it to be an integer.). If you call it a *loop control variable* or a *function argument/parameter/input* depends merely from how you look at it - the way you are using it it is both.

OTOH in the example with the newton method where the `x` variable at step `i`, a.k.a. `x_i`, is called the ***i-th approximation*** or *i-th iteration of x*. At least it is what they call it in the wikipedia article about [iterative methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method). I think our professor usually just said "the `x_i`".

Personally, I often call them the *running variable* (probably just a literal translation from my german-speaking background 'Laufvariable') or simply the *loop variable* - but I don't think these are official terms or anything. Still people usually understand what I mean.